# Can someone explain the reason for this discrepency in speeds?

Tags: mining-hardware, asic, antminer, stratum, bfgminer

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

Firmware is reporting 15TH/s but BFGMiner says its only running at 200GH/s

[image: Here is BFGMiner reporting 200GH/s]

[image: Here is the firmware reporting 14TH/s]